# Why do we drop the s in phrases like "it makes him feel bad"?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to figure when we drop the "s" of verbs who refer to the third person singular. It is clear to me that it happens in the subjunctive and with modal verbs. The sentence below doesn't quite fit in any of the cases:

> It makes him feel bad.

Why is the *s* dropped in this case?

Comment: What's the source of that sentence? Are you sure that's what it said exactly?

Comment: Maybe you mean we write "he *feels* bad," but "makes him **feel** bad"?

Comment: @Laurel the source is a song and not quite the sentece I wrote. It probably should be wrote as Yosef said. The original one is "it makes my head feel like a nightclub", a song from The Vaccines.

Comment: Because "it makes him feels bad" is not grammatical, really. There is only one clause.

Comment: @Lambie two verbs and one clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a matter of "dropping the s". The finite form (which has *-s* in the 3rd person singular of the present) is used only when it is the main verb of the clause.

When it is dependent on another verb - modals, "want to", "have to" "make somebody" - the verb is almost always in the base form (traditionally "infinitive"). The only exceptions are after *HAVE* and *BE*, when it takes other forms, but still not the finite form.

> He feels but *he will feel*, *he must feel*, *he wants to feel*, *he ought to feel*, *make him feel*.

Comment: English is too hard. Him is the accusative but the object is a new clause where him is also the subject. So...regardless of we having two clauses we only consider the principal one?

Comment: It the subordinate clause is finite (eg after _that_, or a relative clause), then its subject will use the subject form of pronouns (eg _I think that he feels bad_; _Somebody who he feels bad about_). If it is not finite - whether infinitive (_You made him feel bad_) participial (_I don't like him feeling bad_) or nominal ("gerund": _The result was him feeling bad_) then it doesn't use the subject form.

Comment: English is actually rather easy, if you're not being taught nonsense. Of course too many people teach that. Excessive attention to dying features like inflection, punctuation, and spelling instead of attention to conversation and contraction, not to mention local variations.

Comment: "I want to go" is usually divided as the finite verb "want" and the full infinitive "to go". (In other words, not "want to" with a bare infinitive "go".) The same applies for "have to . . ." and others.

Comment: There are other "exceptions" besides "have" and "be" that take full infinitive dependents. In fact, so many that I wouldn't call them exceptions at all: "ought", "want", "try", "like", etc. (Or am I misunderstanding you?)

Comment: No my point was that _most_ "auxiliaries" (interpreted broadly) take the basic/infinitive form, but _have_ and _be_ take participles instead. And your point about _have/to go_ vs _have to/go_ is right according to the traditional analysis, but - especially because of the currency of words like _hafta_ and _gonna_ - this analysis is no longer adequate.